# Draw plane via 3 points

Tags: matlab

I have 3 points (1,1,1), (2,2,2), (2,2,0). It is enough to draw plane via these 3 points.

But how to do this in Matlab? I'm planning to use `surf()` function. I do:

```
x=[1 2 2 ]
y=[1 2 2 ]
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y)
```

it creates mesh :

X

```
1 2 2
1 2 2
1 2 2
```

y

```
1 1 1
2 2 2 
2 2 2
```

Problems appeared while construct Z matrix:

Z

```
1 ? ?
? 2 ?
? ? 0
```

I know only 3 points , how to fill other ones defined as `?` ?

Comment: Do you want to create a grid for the plane or what is the question?

Comment: in general question is "how to draw plane via 3 points in Matlab?"

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41937-plot-a-plane-from-3-points

Comment: In some cases it just not draw plane: `plot_line([1,1,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,0])`.  I'm wondering why there are no standard way to draw plane via 3 points.

Comment: This is the vertical plane $x=y$ !

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the fill3 function. See below:

```
p1 = [1 1 1];
p2 = [2 2 2];
p3 = [2 2 0];

points=[p1' p2' p3']; 
fill3(points(1,:),points(2,:),points(3,:),'r')
grid on
```